# Form Gives 400 Bad Request error when using with Spring's ModelAttribute

Tags: spring-mvc

i have html form which i forward to spring controller. Its works fine if i use getParameter but using modelAttribute it says 400 bad request error.

> Here is my controller Code

```
@Controller
public class BookController {



    @RequestMapping (value="/addBook")
    public String addBook(@ModelAttribute Book book){

        System.out.println(book.getBookName());
        bookService.addBooks(book);


        return "index";
    }


}
```

> This is Book model Code

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "Book")
public class Book {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="ID",columnDefinition = "BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT")
        private long bookId;
        @Column(name="book_code",columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL")
        private String bookCode;
        private String bookName;
        private String author;
        @Temporal (TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date dateOfArrival;
        private Double price;
        private String rackNo;
        private int numberOfBook;
        private String subjectCode;

        public Book() {
            super();
        }

        public Book(String bookCode, String bookName, String author,
                Date dateOfArrival, Double price, String rackNo,
                int numberOfBook, String subjectCode) {
            super();
            this.bookCode = bookCode;
            this.bookName = bookName;
            this.author = author;
            this.dateOfArrival = dateOfArrival;
            this.price = price;
            this.rackNo = rackNo;
            this.numberOfBook = numberOfBook;
            this.subjectCode = subjectCode;
        }



        public String getBookCode() {
            return bookCode;
        }



        public long getBookId() {
            return bookId;
        }

        public void setBookId(long bookId) {
            this.bookId = bookId;
        }

        public void setBookCode(String bookCode) {
            this.bookCode = bookCode;
        }

        public String getBookName() {
            return bookName;
        }

        public void setBookName(String bookName) {
            this.bookName = bookName;
        }

        public String getAuthor() {
            return author;
        }

        public void setAuthor(String author) {
            this.author = author;
        }

        public Date getDateOfArrival() {
            return dateOfArrival;
        }

        public void setDateOfArrival(Date dateOfArrival) {
            this.dateOfArrival = dateOfArrival;
        }

        public Double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(Double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getRackNo() {
            return rackNo;
        }

        public void setRackNo(String rackNo) {
            this.rackNo = rackNo;
        }

        public int getNumberOfBook() {
            return numberOfBook;
        }

        public void setNumberOfBook(int numberOfBook) {
            this.numberOfBook = numberOfBook;
        }

        public String getSubjectCode() {
            return subjectCode;
        }

        public void setSubjectCode(String subjectCode) {
            this.subjectCode = subjectCode;
        }

}
```

> I have doubt that the problem is due to using date 
>   Please Help me out

Comment: I would add this parameter, BindingResult result, to your controller method and debug the method to see exacty the reason of the error. If the date is your problem, probably you will need to bind the date

Comment: did you check the response?

Answer (score 0):

I would try 2 things.

1. In your Model add this:

   ```
   //here use the same pattern of date your send from the view
   @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
   private Date dateOfArrival;
   ```
2. In your controller

   ```
   @RequestMapping (value="/addBook")
   public String addBook(@ModelAttribute Book book, BindingResult result){
   ...
   ```

Then you will be able to debug your method and know the problem.